# UWP - in-app products - speed of GetAppLicenseAsync()

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, in-app-purchase, windows-store

I am migrating a

- Windows 8.1 app which used the `Windows.ApplicationModel.Store` namespace for IAPs to
- Windows 10 UWP with the `Windows.Services.Store` namespace

For determining the license status of in-app items, the former had a `LicenseInformation` property whereas the latter has a `GetAppLicenseAsync()` method.

So, with the former the information about IAPs was (seemed to be?) there instantaneous, whereas with the new method, the information could take longer.

My question: Is the newer concept really slower or is the speed the same and the new async method just reflects the fact that getting the information has never been instantaneous?

My app needs the information about all purchased items already at app start. So, the only way I see is that I call `GetAppLicenseAsync()` at app start and wait until the information is there before I show the user interface.

**Edit 2017-07-25:**

**My question in short is: Is there a time of how long the `GetAppLicenseAsync()` method will take *at most*?**

Answer (score 0):

> Is the newer concept really slower or is the speed the same and the
>   new async method just reflects the fact that getting the information
>   has never been instantaneous?

How long will it take before you can see the user interface when you call `GetAppLicenseAsync()` method?

For me, the API in new namespace is instantaneous. Maybe your request delay can be related with your network environment. However, the result of `LicenseInfomation` is stored in the local so that it can be instantaneous as you can get the info offline. For the new namespace, you can also store the app license info in the local storage when user purchase that item for the first time so that the process of your app starting will not be affected by the network environment.

Moreover, according to the note in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials-using-the-windows-applicationmodel-store-namespace):

> If your app targets Windows 10, version 1607, or later, we recommend that you use members of the `Windows.Services.Store` namespace instead of the `Windows.ApplicationModel.Store` namespace. The `Windows.Services.Store` namespace supports the latest add-on types, such as Store-managed consumable add-ons, **and is designed to be compatible with future types of products and features supported by Windows Dev Center and the Store**. The `Windows.Services.Store` namespace is also designed to have better performance.

So, it's appropriate to migrate your namespace to `Windows.Services.Store`.

Comment: "For me, the API in new namespace is instantaneous." Why? Why is it an async method then? Maybe you got a very fast internet connection. Sure, I could store the information by myself locally, but what if the user re-installs the app or installs it on a new computer?